# border color for dynamically created entry inside listview is not working as expected in xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin

`I have used custom renderer class and on focus of an entry, border color is changing.

By default entry wont be enabled, once user selects an icon, then entry is getting enabled and then on focus, color is changing to something else.

I have an Image Button(to add), I am using a list view, inside that i have an entry and an imageButton(to delete).
On click of a button, entry and imageButton(to delete) is dynamically creating.

**Once i select the imageButton(to delete), it is deleting that particular entry and then i am adding again by tapping on imageButton(to add).**

After that when i tried to put focus on that entry, border color is not changing as expected.

Custom Renderer is not working when there's a list which comprises insertion and deletion operations.`

.xaml

```
<StackLayout x:Name="vehicleListLayout" Margin="40,0" VerticalOptions="Fill" >
 <ScrollView>
   <ListView x:Name="MyList" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionsList}"
              Footer="" VerticalOptions="Fill" SelectionMode="None" HeightRequest="300" AutomationId="AutomationId_ProfileVehicleList"
             IsEnabled="False">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                   <Grid Margin="0" RowSpacing="0">

                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> 
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                       <local:BorderedEntryRenderer
                           x:Name="VehicleEntry"
                           Text="{Binding VehicleNumber1}" WidthRequest="180"
                           Margin="5" VerticalOptions="Start" AutomationId="AutomationId_ProfileVehicle"/>

                      <ImageButton
                          x:Name="DeleteButton"
                          Margin="5" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand, Source={x:Reference MyList}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Grid.Column="1" Source="baseline_remove_black_24"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="25" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    AutomationId="AutomationId_ProfileDeleteVehicle"/>

                   </Grid>
               </ViewCell>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
     </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

viewModel

```
    private void AddItems(object obj)
    {
        Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles();
        CollectionsList.Insert(0, vehicles);
    }

    private void OnDeleteTapped(object obj)
    {
        var content = obj as Vehicles;
        CollectionsList.Remove(content);
    }
```

BorderedEntryRenderer class(Common)

```
namespace DriverTracker
{
public class BorderedEntryRenderer : Entry
{
    public static BorderedEntryRenderer Instance { get; } = new BorderedEntryRenderer();

    public static readonly BindableProperty DefaultBorderColorProperty =
     BindableProperty.Create(
         nameof(DefaultBorderColor),
         typeof(Color),
         typeof(BorderedEntryRenderer),
         Color.LightGray);

    public Color DefaultBorderColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(DefaultBorderColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DefaultBorderColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedBorderColorProperty =
     BindableProperty.Create(
         nameof(SelectedBorderColor),
         typeof(Color),
         typeof(BorderedEntryRenderer),
         Color.LightSkyBlue);



    public Color SelectedBorderColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedBorderColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedBorderColorProperty, value); }
    }
```

Android

```
namespace DriverTracker.Droid
{
public class AndroidBorderedEntryRenderer: EntryRenderer
{
    public AndroidBorderedEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var view = (BorderedEntryRenderer)Element;


        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            var gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
            gradientDrawable.SetCornerRadius((float)view.CornerRadius);
            gradientDrawable.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
            gradientDrawable.SetStroke(view.BorderWidth, view.DefaultBorderColor.ToAndroid());

            e.NewElement.Unfocused += (sender, evt) =>
            {
                gradientDrawable.SetStroke(view.BorderWidth, view.DefaultBorderColor.ToAndroid());
            };
            e.NewElement.Focused += (sender, evt) =>
            {
                gradientDrawable.SetStroke(view.BorderWidth, view.SelectedBorderColor.ToAndroid());
            };

            Control.SetBackground(gradientDrawable);
        }
    }
}
```

iOS

```
namespace DriverTracker.iOS
{
public class iOSBorderedEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            var view = (BorderedEntryRenderer)Element;

            Control.Layer.CornerRadius = (float)((BorderedEntryRenderer)Element).CornerRadius;
            Control.Layer.BorderWidth = view.BorderWidth;
            Control.Layer.BorderColor = view.DefaultBorderColor.ToCGColor();

            e.NewElement.Unfocused += (sender, evt) =>
            {
                Control.Layer.BorderColor = view.DefaultBorderColor.ToCGColor();
            };
            e.NewElement.Focused += (sender, evt) =>
            {
                Control.Layer.BorderColor = view.SelectedBorderColor.ToCGColor();
            };

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your BorderedEntryRenderer codes ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT  I have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplify your code and test it,it works well.Did you forget to add an `ExportRenderer` attribute to the custom renderer class to specify that it will be used to render the Xamarin.Forms control ?

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BorderedEntryRenderer), typeof(AndroidBorderedEntryRenderer))]
namespace  DriverTracker.Droid
```

and

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BorderedEntryRenderer), typeof(iOSBorderedEntryRenderer ))]
namespace  DriverTracker.iOS
```

**Update**:

add the `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` to your listview.

```
<ListView  CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" x:Name="MyList" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionsList}"
          Footer="" VerticalOptions="Fill" SelectionMode="None" HeightRequest="300" AutomationId="AutomationId_ProfileVehicleList"
         IsEnabled="False">
    ...
</ListView  >
```

Comment: No i added all these things. Its working for normal scenarios. I am getting issue when entry is inside a list view that i am dynamically creating on click of a button

Comment: Do you have an Index requirement for entry? If not, you can use CollectionsList.Add or CollectionsList.Insert(CollectionsList.Count,vehicles); method,i found if you create the entry at the last index,it works.

Comment: I checked, if i add and i focused on the entry, border color is changed, delete that field and create a new one, then focus, border color is not changing

Comment: @SaumyaSaloni i update the answer,you could check it see if it works for you.

Comment: adding CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" worked, thanx a lot.